# 2000s (maybe 90s?) movie with flying faces that could manipulate electronics

Tags: story-identification

Best genre guess would be sci-fi/comedy, the atmosphere seemed pretty unserious.

I watched this in early 2000s, while in Russia. It was definitely dubbed - you could hear the original language, but cannot say with certainty if it was English or another language, likely English though.

I don't remember a lot of the plot but the main "thing" were those entities? ghosts? not sure, they were different objects with a human face on them, I think a clock was one of them. Looked kinda cartoonishly CGI but the faces were "real". The Russian dub called them for something that sounded like "dot". They could float around and talk. Also, at some point a person got turned into one close to the end, I think their entity looked like a gear.

Also, there was a scientist who invented a gun that could do something to them (possibly teleport them to where they came from), I recall a scene where he was presenting the gun to someone else and he was using all kinds of technical names he came up with which all became three letter acronyms with the same letter. Even the gun had a name like that. I am not sure whether how well that was corresponding to the original language versus the dub, but it was had words "Derportator", "Dot" (like the entities) and some third word that started with a D, the scientist sounded very excited that he could call it the "DDD". Also, at the end of that scene, the other person seemed to catch onto the idea of the acronyms and tried to make one as well but the scientist was not amused.

The climax of the movie involved a bunch of these entities going to some kind of a control panel (either  a weapons platform, or perhaps a nuclear plant) and somehow taking over the different dials and controls, messing it up more and more. They were about to cause something really bad to happen, but then someone did something (I really don't remember) and they stopped doing that, detached from the panel and averted the catastrophe. When they took the panels over, I halfway remember the clock shaped one flying over and on top of some dial, and then it kinda disappeared but the dial's hand started going haywire. There was also a control that looked like the throttle of an aircraft that also started going up and down once it got possessed.

It could have been an episode of some series, too, but I think it was a movie.